# Not able to run Statistics Collector Sample in WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.3

Tags: java, registry, wso2, publisher, wso2-bam

I followed the exact steps mentioned in [Statistics Collector Sample](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance453/Statistics+Collector+Sample).

But events are not getting published, I tried to debug it and found that no `system.out.println()` lines(used for debugging in StatisticsCollectorServiceComponent.java) are getting printed in the server log files.

Is there anything missing because greg is not invoking the `activate()` method of the class StatisticsCollectorServiceComponent.java.

Comment: Did you create any wsdl or service? You need to do one of the above to get the data to be published.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ragavan. I have not created any wsdl and service as it is not mentioned in the sample link below http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance453/Statistics+Collector+Sample Do I need to create it? please suggest how I can proceed?

Comment: Follow this to get the steps for creating WSDL http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance453/Managing+WSDLs

Comment: Hi Ragavan, Sorry I misinterpreted it I thought you are saying we need to create WSDL for publishing data, I have already added WSDLs and service there, and  data is not getting published and  println() statements in the code are also not getting printed after doing changes in WSDL and service like adding properties, comments, ratings etc. by different users.